# Systemd Timer Template after boot?

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I have a templated timer that calls a templated unit. I use the following to enable and start them:

```
sudo systemctl enable ping@.timer
sudo systemctl enable ping@service
sudo systemctl start ping@hello.timer
```

This works as expected, and the timer activates `ping@hello.service` as expected. However this doesn't persist after reboots, presumably because I didn't enable the instance of the timer. But the following fails with a "does not exist" error:

```
sudo systemctl enable ping@hello.timer
```

How can I have a templated timer start at each boot?

Comment: What is the actual error you received? What version of systemd?

Comment: Error was with me - see posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was with me - the "trick" is to use two enables on the timer:

```
sudo systemctl enable ping@.timer
sudo systemctl enable ping@service
sudo systemctl enable ping@hello.timer
```

I was getting an error as I was trying to enable the instance of the timer before the template.